# Unable to subscribe to a google pub sub topic using a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-deployment-manager, google-iam

I was trying to understand example given in google cloud samples present in this link

[IAM Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/iam/jinja)

This example creates a service account, a VM, and a Pub/Sub topic. The VM runs as the service account, and the service account has subscriber access to the Pub/Sub topic, thereby giving services and applications running on the VM access to the Pub/Sub topic.

However when I am trying to deploy this example I am getting below error

```
The fingerprint of the deployment is a-v3HjAHciZeSLuE-vSeZw==
Waiting for create [operation-1525502430976-56b6fb6809800-dbd09909-c5d681b2]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1525502430976-56b6fb6809800-dbd09909-c5d681b2]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/test-dp/resources/my-pubsub-topic
  message: '{"ResourceType":"pubsub.v1.topic","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"User
    not authorized to perform this action.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":[],"statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fresh-deck-194307/topics/my-pubsub-topic:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

It mentions that User doesn't have permission to perform this action.
I am unable to understand which user it is mentioning about. 
Since I am the project owner and my account is the owner of project, I should be able to deploy a script which can set IAM policy for subscribing to a pubsub topic.

Might be my understanding is wrong above. Could somebody help to understand why this example is failing?

Also I hope if any additional configuration is needed for this example to run, it should be mentioned in README file. But there are no instructions.

Comment: Which user or service account is deploying through DM and does that user/account have the "setIamPolicy" permission?

Comment: @PatrickW user is the project owner and deployment manager is being executed from cloud shell.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing and getting the same error. Seems to be an issue setting the IAM policy in the "pubsub_topic.jinja" file. This might be an issue with the API, I had a similar weird error message when I tried to set IAM policy through REST using the IAM API.

Comment: I tried deploying it again this evening and now I'm no longer getting the 403 error. It might have been a transient issue. Either way the deployment now works with no change

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that APIs for all resources that you're trying to deploy are enabled.
- Use `gcloud auth list` command to make sure that the account with enough permissions is the active one.
- Use `gcloud config list` command to make sure that the default project or other settings are correct.

Comment: yes all things are checked and valid. Still its not working.

Comment: I’ve tested the deployment on my end. It worked for me. If it still doesn’t work on your end, it will have to be investigated. I would recommend that you create a new issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui).